# Add a legend to geom_segment

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I add a title to the *geom_segment* plot below that has a title of "work order" and  below the title has a red line with the text "Type 1" and a blue line with text "Type 2"?

```
df = data.frame(time1=as.POSIXct(c("2012-04-04 09:23:33","2012-04-04 11:33:55")),
                  time2=as.POSIXct(c("2012-04-04 10:05:04","2012-04-04 13:42:24")), 
                  y1=c(1,2),
                  y2=c(1,2),
                  color = c("red","blue"))

ggplot(df)  + geom_segment(aes(x = time1, y = y1, xend = time2, yend = y2), 
             colour= df$color, size = 4, data = df)
```

Answer (score 3):

Map the grouping variable to `color` in `aes` and set the name, values, breaks and labels in `scale_color_manual`.

```
ggplot(df)  + 
    geom_segment(aes(x = time1, y = y1, xend = time2, yend = y2, color = color), 
               size = 4, data = df) +
    scale_color_manual(name = "work order", values = c("blue", "red"), 
                    breaks = c("red", "blue"), labels = c("Type 1", "Type 2"))
```

You could also use `scale_color_identity`, which allows skipping the setting of the values but you then need to include `guide = "legend"` as it defaults to `"none"`.

```
ggplot(df)  + 
    geom_segment(aes(x = time1, y = y1, xend = time2, yend = y2, color = color), 
               size = 4, data = df) +
    scale_color_identity(name = "work order", guide = "legend",  
                    breaks = c("red", "blue"), labels = c("Type 1", "Type 2"))
```

[image]